# When I create an event from a start date and end date in a google sheet, the end date in the calendar is one day earlier

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

I've written a simple script to take a start date and end date from 2 cells in a spreadsheet and create a calendar event. The cells are formatted as a date and will show the calendar dropdown to select a date. Time zones on both the sheet and the calendar are the same. The function takes in the onEdit event from the spreadsheet. The function itself is working and successfully creates the event in the calendar, but with the end date being one day earlier than the date specified in the spreadsheet.

gets the start date based on the edited row and the column with the start dates
`var onSiteStartDate = ss.getRange(editedRow, onSiteStartDateRangeCol).getValue();`
gets the end date in the same fashion
`var onSiteEndDate = ss.getRange(editedRow, onSiteEndDateRangeCol).getValue();`
Creates the event based on those dates with a title concatenated from other cells in the row
 
`onSiteCal.createAllDayEvent(onSiteEventTitle, onSiteStartDate, onSiteEndDate);`

logging start and end date in the console returns `Wed Oct 09 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)Thu Oct 17 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)`

However in the calendar, the event starts on the 9th, and the final day of the event is the 16th.

I've fiddled with the time zones in both the spreadsheet and the calendar with no luck.

What's going on here?

Comment: `Thu Oct 17 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500` - that end is at the very moment the day starts - perhaps that's the problem ... if something ends at the very moment the day starts, is it really occurring on that day? add `86399999` milliseconds to the end date (or just one day since you know with time 0:00:00 it doesn't include that day)

Comment: Am I understanding it correctly as in that for a full day event on October 1, the start of the event is `2019-10-01 00:00:00` and the end of the event is `2019-10-02 00:00:00`? If so, what would be your expected result?

Comment: @JaromandaX I manipulated the time zones so that the end date output is ```Thu Oct 17 2019 01:00:00 GMT-0500``` , but no luck. 

@JoachimIsaksson the expected calendar event from the dates you gave would be a two day event, beginning start-of-day on the first and ending end-of-day on the 2nd - covering two full days in the calendar. The documentation for the ```createAllDayEvent()``` method states that time is disregarded.

Comment: I suggested adding a full day, and you instead add an hour ... try adding 24 hours instead

Comment: @JaromandaX gotcha. Ultimately i re-wrote the script to add a full day to the event. it's inconvenient because I'm now dealing with two separate end dates, but it is what it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79918563) with createAllDayEvent(), as it is not working as expected. I used the same date format as specified in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createalldayeventtitle,-startdate,-enddate,-options):

```
CalendarApp.createAllDayEvent("All day", new Date('October 3, 2019'), new Date('October 6, 2019'));
```

The event in the Calendar is created from October 3 to October *5*, when it should be October *6*.

However, as you are working with dates *and* time, I recommend you to use [createEvent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createeventtitle,-starttime,-endtime,-options), which uses the format 'July 20, 1969 20:00:00 UTC' and works as expected.

Regarding the bug, you can click on the star next to the issue number to receive updates, and I also will report it.

Comment: No luck. I manipulated the date in several ways using the SimpleDateFormat and used the ```createEvent()``` and ```setTime()``` (for a separate function to update an existing event) methods but the end result was still the same. Ultimate i decided to just add a day to the end date. This is mildly inconvenient, but it is what it is. Thanks!